# Redirect all HTTP to HTTPS without ELB

Tags: swift, perfect

I'm trying to redirect all my APIs and web HTTP requests to HTTPS in Swift Perfect. I have deployed code into AWS. When I Googled, all I'm getting is using ELB which I'm not using. Are there any workaround to redirect to https port inside code?

Comment: I don't know why it is voted down. At least a reason would have been satisfying before voting down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lot of research and people guidance I figured out a solution. Posting it so that other don't have to spend time on this on Perfect

For redirect all HTTP to HTTPS here is the solution

```
let mainDomain = "www.<your domain>.com(or anything)"

var nonSecureRoutes = Routes()
nonSecureRoutes.add(method: .get, uri: "/**", handler: {
    request, response in
    response.setHeader(.location, value: "https://\(request.header(.host) ?? mainDomain)\(request.uri)")
        .completed(status: .movedPermanently)
})

let certPath = "/cert/path.pem"
let keyPath = "key/path.pem"

var certVerifyMode = OpenSSLVerifyMode()
certVerifyMode = .sslVerifyPeer

do {
    try HTTPServer.launch(
        .server(name: mainDomain, port: 80, routes: nonSecureRoutes),
        .secureServer(TLSConfiguration(certPath: certPath, keyPath: keyPath, certVerifyMode: certVerifyMode), name: mainDomain, port: 443, routes: routes))

} catch PerfectError.networkError(let err, let msg) {
    print("Network error thrown: \(err) \(msg)")
}
```